# Pass data to dompdf (not with Laravel)

Tags: php, dompdf

I have seen a lot of answers using Laravel but I am not using a framework and want to pass some data. Is it possible? I tried passing `$data` as a second argument to `loadHtml` but that does not work.

```
        $options = new Options();
        $options->set('defaultFont', 'Arial');
        $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

        $data = ['test' => 'here is the data I want to pass'];
    
        ob_start();
        require("mypath/templates/pdf-file.php");
        $html = ob_get_contents();
        ob_get_clean();
    
        
        $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    
        $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
        
        $dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
        $dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', true);

        $dompdf->render();

        $dompdf->stream();
```

Comment: @DarkBee funny, I tried that before and it didn't seem to work yet giving it another go now and it worked! Brilliant, thanks! Can you add that as your answer so I can accept please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables defined before a require or include are accessible in the required/included file. This means if `pdf-file.php` is the file which generates the `HTML`, you can just use the variable `$data` inside `pdf-file.php` to fill the (dynamic) information required to build the PDF